# Orchard CMS Confirmation message appears on desktop but not on mobile or tablets. Trying to fix so it works on all

Tags: css, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have a custom form module installed for a contact us page.

When on a desktop the form will give a confirmation message either that your form was accepted or denied. However this is only working on a desktop

I'm trying to figure out whats causing it to stop working on other devices. I have the ResponsiveThemeMachine theme installed but I looked through the css files and saw nothing about the class .message-Information (which is what the confirmation message uses)

I'm not sure where else to look as to why it wouldn't work on anything but a desktop.

Comment: I partially solved this if anyone has the same problem. I had to add a widget in the message field so what I did was created an HTML widget and set the title to not appear and left the body blank and set it to only appear on the contact page. It did push the content down a little bit but now my message works on all devices.

Comment: The responsive theme machine has media queries in the css that can hide zones on smaller screens. One of those is probably hiding the zone where the notifications appear.

Comment: I actually looked through that css file because that's the main one i use to style the site. In the media queries I couldn't find anything. One thing I did notice though is if i "disabled" the css class for the message on the desktop it would appear without any css but on the mobile (this is after i got it working) it would show with css still. So it think there is another hidden css for it somewhere but I don't know how to inspect element on my phone...

Comment: Oh boy. Don't inspect on your phone. All modern desktop browsers can emulate smaller devices from their F12 tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved this if anyone has the same problem. I had to add a widget in the message field so what I did was created an HTML widget and set the title to not appear and left the body blank and set it to only appear on the contact page. It did push the content down a little bit but now my message works on all devices